# How do I export multiple SVGs from Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg, automation

How do I export SVG images from multiple artboards in a batch process using Adobe Illustrator CC

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does "Save/Export -> SVG" not do what you need?

Comment: SVG Option is not there

Comment: What version of Illustrator are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using CS6 (not sure about earlier versions) then you need to *save* as SVG, there is no SVG export option.

> File → Save As → SVG (svg)

In CC there is a new *export* option for SVG.

> File → Export → SVG (svg)

In both cases, make sure to check "Use Artboards" to export the contents of your artboards as individual SVG files.

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html

Answer (score 3):

Use: `File > Export > Export for screens`.
Set the format to SVG.
This pretty powerful and allows you to select each artboard (rather than asset) you want to export. You can also export multiple formats in one go (great for backup PNGs for example).